# Animating a UIImageView with delay

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am animating a UIImageView in this way:

```
int timerAnimation = 0.0f;

for (UIImageView* img in imageArray) {

timerAnimation = timerAnimation + 1.0f;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:timerAnimation
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void) {
                     img.frame = CGRectMake(20, img.frame.origin.y, 710, 60);
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

I want to reduce the delay time, but I noticed that if I put any value inferior than 1.0,

e.g.

```
timerAnimation + 0.5f;
```

Then all the objects move at the save time, as if there was no delay. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an int!

```
int timerAnimation = 0.0f;
```

It should be a float instead:

```
CGFloat timerAnimation = 0.0f;
```

An int doesn't support fractions, so you can only add whole numbers to it (1.0) and not halfs (0.5)